# Prepend Image to First Child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple Chrome extension that removes YouTube's feed from the page and replaces it with an image.  I can remove the feed, but placing the image has proven troublesome.  I just want to replace the feed with an image.  The code is below, any pointers or docs would greatly be appreciated!

```
var feed = document.getElementById('feed');
var feedsParent = feed.parent();
feed.parentNode.removeChild(feed);
feedsParent.firstChild.prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://www.sgt.gr/_repository/file/1/Resize/images/sun-ra-2_site.jpg" />')
```

Comment: `feed.parent()` actually works?

Comment: The native `prepend()` method only accepts textNode values or Element objects. If you're intending to inject some HTML, you may want to use jQuery's `append()` method instead

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? Are you actually using it? It's hardly necessary today *especially* for a Chrome extension.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yeah, I don't think feed.parent() works at all.  Can somebody suggest how to properly select the parent of feed and store to a variable?

Comment: You're already doing it on your third line of code. ;)

Comment: I guess the problem is if I remove feed from the site, the parent element won't be accessible unless I store it to a variable beforehand?

Comment: Right. Store it before you remove it. `var feedsParent = feed.parentNode; feedsParent.removeChild(feed); feedsParent.firstChild.insertAdjacentHTML(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `.insertAdjacentHTML` instead.

```
var feed = document.getElementById('feed');
var feedsParent = feed.parentNode;
feedsParent.removeChild(feed);
feedsParent.firstChild.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", '<img id="theImg" src="http://www.sgt.gr/_repository/file/1/Resize/images/sun-ra-2_site.jpg" />')
```

This will let you inject new nodes that get parsed from HTML, into various positions relative to the given element.

I assume that `.firstChild` is in fact pointing to an Element node. If not, you can use `.firstElementChild`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing jquery and vanilla javascript?
Try using jquery only..

```
var feed = $('#feed');
var feedsParent = feed.parent();
feed.remove();
feedsParent.prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://www.sgt.gr/_repository/file/1/Resize/images/sun-ra-2_site.jpg"/>');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: WOW!  Thank you, this is my 2nd day of JQuery and building an extension, so I am a little overwhelmed, thank you and everybody for the input!!

Comment: Using jQuery for an extension is massive overhead that isn't necessary.

Comment: @SamParsons: You're doubling your burden of learning by trying to learn two APIs. One is built in, fast and easy, and the other (jQuery) is an unnecessary, bloated remnant from circa-2011 web development.

Comment: It did have 1, but I guess not anymore.